# How can redirect users by role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, roles

Well, i'm newbie in ROR.
I need redirect the user to some page, this run but no works.
Always redirect to link 4, for the else option, i'm check the database, and the users have a role:
Where is the mistake? Thanks!

```
module ApplicationHelper

def role_link(user)
  user = User.find(1)
  case user.rol
    when 'A'
      url = 'link 1'
    when 'C'
      url = 'link 2'
    when 'E' 
      url = 'link 3'
  else
    url = 'link 4'
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you try any tests?

Comment: As I could do? What do you suggest? Magee

Comment: possible that you are just missing an _e_ at the end of of your case statement? `case user.role`

Comment: No Dimitry, it's fine. Well, thanks.

Comment: I'm do it with case and if endif, and is equal. Can't find the mistake.

Comment: When you do `user = User.find(1)`, you  shadow the parameter with local variable. Try removing this line.

Comment: Don't restrict your troubleshooting to code. Look at the data, too. What role does user.id 1 have? Once you fix your code so you're not hardcoding the user, look at the role for whatever user you're passing as an argument.

Comment: BINGO! TeWU. Now work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to @TeWu, this question is closed because there was a variable overwrite of the beginning of the `role_link` method.

So this is the solution:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def role_link(user)
    case user.rol
      when 'A'
        url = 'link 1'
      when 'C'
        url = 'link 2'
      when 'E' 
        url = 'link 3'
    else
      url = 'link 4'
    end
  end
end
```